# Sufficient condition for two holomorphic functions to have the same zeros.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f,g$ two holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{D}$ with the following properties:
\begin{align*} 
f(z) \overline{f(\overline{z})} = g(z) \overline{g(\overline{z})} \quad  \forall z \in \mathbb{D}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
|f(z)|=|g(z)| \quad \forall z \in e^{i \theta} (-1,1) 
\end{align*}
for some $\theta \notin \pi \mathbb{Q}$. My goal is to show that the zeros of $f$ and $g$ are the same, i.e. $f(z)=0$ iff. $g(z)=0$. I am not a 100% sure that the conditions are sufficient since there is only a proof which I don't quite understand. The idea is the following:

Let $\mathcal{Z}=\left (Z(f) \cup Z(g) \right ) \setminus \left ( Z(f) \cap Z(g) \right )$ be the symmetric difference of the two zero sets. We can see that $\mathcal{Z}=\overline{\mathcal{Z}}$ and $\mathcal{Z} \cap \mathbb{R} = \emptyset$. Since $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ for all $z \in e^{i \theta} (-1,1)$, we have $\mathcal{Z}=$Ref$\theta \mathcal{Z}$, where Ref$\theta$ refers to a reflection with respect to the segment $e^{i \theta} (-1,1)$. From these we can conclude that $\mathcal{Z}=$Rot$2\theta \mathcal{Z}$ ,where Rot$2\theta$ refers to a counterclockwise $2\theta$-rotation with respect to $0$. Since $\theta \notin \pi \mathbb{Q}$, either $\mathcal{Z}$ is uncountable or $\mathcal{Z} = \emptyset$. But why is this the case? If it is, then we have $\mathcal{Z} = \emptyset$, since $\mathcal{Z}$ must be discrete, and thus $Z(f)=Z(g)$. So yeah, I would appreciate any help on that last step of the proof. Would this work for any set $\mathcal{Z}$ with said properties? (I.e. a set $\mathcal{Z} \subset \mathbb{D}$ s.th. $\mathcal{Z}=\overline{\mathcal{Z}}, \mathcal{Z} \cap \mathbb{R} =\emptyset$ and $\mathcal{Z}=$Ref$\theta \mathcal{Z}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with problem

> Let $\mathcal{Z} \subset \mathbb{D}$ s.th.
> $\mathcal{Z}=\overline{\mathcal{Z}}$ and $\mathcal{Z}=$Ref$\theta \mathcal{Z}, 0\notin \mathcal{Z}$

1. Given $\theta/\pi$ is irrational and $x\in\mathcal{Z} \neq \emptyset, x \neq 0,$ it follows that $\mathcal{Z}$ should contain infinite number of points $\mathcal{X}=\{xe^{2\theta n}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ (using fact re. rotations),
2. So there is cluster point in $\mathcal{X}$ (as any circumference is compact) and thus $f\equiv0$ or $g\equiv0$ ($f$ or $g$ or both should have cluster point among zeros).
3. So both $f$ and $g$ are identically 0 (from identity on $\mathbb{D}$).
4. Contradiction, as $\mathcal{Z} = \emptyset$ in the case when $f\equiv g\equiv 0.$

Comment: Can you elaborate on why we need the fact that $\theta / \pi$ is irrational?

Comment: Because, otherwise $\mathcal{X}$ is finite and $\mathcal{X}$ may not have cluster point. Note that $xe^{2\theta n} = xe^{2\theta m}$ iff $2\theta (n-m) = 2\pi k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$ iff $m=n, k=0$ or $\theta/\pi=k/(n-m)\in\mathbb{Q}.$

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now